# PHP PostgreSQL prepared statement without parameters

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

I was wondering if it's possible to prepare statements using PHP's pgsql library that do not require parameters.

I'm really used to preparing all my SQL statements in the beginning of a program instead of when I need them so my code always looks similar to this

```
<?php

    $pgsqlCon = // code to connect


    // prepare SQL statements

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table01 " .
           "WHERE t01_idno >= $1";
    pg_prepare($pgsqlCon, "table01_cur", $sql);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table02 " .
           "WHERE t02_idno = $1";
    pg_prepare($pgsqlCon, "table02_sel", $sql);


    // start main

    $table01 = pg_execute($pgsqlCon, "table01_cur", array('1'));
    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($table01)) {
        echo "<span>found something<br /></span>";
    }

    $table02 = pg_execute($pgsqlCon, "table02_sel", array('1'));
    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($table02)) {
        echo "<span>found something else<br /></span>";
    }


?>
```

So I would like to prepare statements that don't require parameters in this way as well if that is possible.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `pg_*` functions but I would start with trying it using an empty array as the third parameter. Or have you done that already?

Comment: Ah passing the empty array worked, I tried to leave off the array completely which was the thing breaking it, thanks a bunch. Would you like to post that as an answer so that I can accept it as the right one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and sadly this usage is not documented in [the official documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-execute.php).

Looking at it you can see that the third argument is not optional (i.e. not in brackets `[..]`) and indeed, as the above comment says, passing an empty `array()` as the third argument works.

So after preparing a statement with no arguments one could execute it like so:

`$rs = pg_execute($connection, $stmt, array());`

Comment: yeah i mean im not sure if there are any performance benefits of using prepared statements in php pgsql but it still would be nice to have documentation about some less conventional uses